# Number of unique variable solutions of an incomplete matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Consider the simple linear system:
$$
3 x_1 + 2x_2 = 4 \\
5x_3 = 9
$$

and the corresponding matrix form Ax=b:
$$
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5  \end{array} \right)   
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3  \end{array} \right)   
= 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
4 \\ 9  \end{array} \right)   
$$

We have that $x_3$  admits exactly one solution (9/5), while $x_1$ and $x_2$ admit more than one solution.

**Question**
Given a system $Ax=b$ can we determine the number of variables that be univocally determined (those with exactly one solution) without solving the system and check "manually" (Gaussian elimination + inspection of the echelon form)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}3&2&0\\0&0&5\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is in [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).  The columns corresponding to non-pivots are free, and hence may be any value.  In this example the pivots are in the first and third columns, so the second variable ($x_2$) is free.  However, some of the pivot columns also might vary.  If a pivot is the only nonzero element of its row, then it has a unique value.  In this example, that's the third column ($x_3$).  If instead there are free variables in its row, then that variable can assume any value, as those free variables vary.  In this example, that's the first column ($x_1$).

However you can read off all this information only if the matrix is in row echelon form.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is exactly what I mean with "manual inspection". So there are no simple way to address this problem in case for instance of random matrix?

Comment: That is correct, for a general matrix you need to put it in row echelon form first.  There is no way to tell at a glance.